# trying to combine two queries as a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables as shown below. I want to combine and write a single query which now i'm getting results writing two query's.

Table1: userProduct

```
pid    productName

1     ipad
2     mobile
3     tv
4     laptop
5     desktop
6     tablet
```

Table2:userTable

```
id    username     pid
1      tom     1
2      john        1
3      joann       1
4      steve       3
5      ann         4
6      dexter      4
7      ryann       6
8      sam         6
```

Below are the two query's which i want to write as single query but get the same results which i'm getting by writing two queries.

```
select productname from userProduct; //it returns 6 rows

select up.pid as pid,ut.username as name from
usertable ut,userproduct up where ut.pid = up.pid; //returns 8 rows
```

From the single query can i get the distinct product names(6 rows) and the matching rows with condition `ut.pid=up.pid`(it returns 8 rows)

Comment: It's not that clear to me. Can you please post the needed result?

Comment: I want to get the productnames(6 product names) which are in userproduct table and get all the matching records ut.pid = up.pid from userproduct and usertable from a single query..currently in my post above i achieved the same result using two queries..

Comment: select up.productname as productname,ut.username as name from
usertable ut,userproduct up where ut.pid = up.pid; //returns 8 rows

Comment: Can you please post the result you need to get, as data? for example, how many rows do you need to get? 8? 6? and what have you tried so far and what is the issue with your code?

Answer (score 2):

You can either get each user and all the products they have, which is basically what you were doing but including the product name (and using ANSI join syntax):

```
select ut.id, ut.username, ut.pid, up.productname
from userTable ut
join userProduct up on up.pid = ut.pid
order by ut.id, up.pid;

        ID USERNAME        PID PRODUCTNAME 
---------- -------- ---------- ------------
         1 tom               1 ipad        
         2 john              1 ipad        
         3 joann             1 ipad        
         4 steve             3 tv          
         5 ann               4 laptop      
         6 dexter            4 laptop      
         7 ryann             6 tablet      
         8 sam               6 tablet
```

or you can get the products with an aggregated list of all the users with that product:

```
select up.pid, up.productname,
  listagg(ut.username, ',') within group (order by ut.id) as usernames
from userProduct up
join userTable ut on ut.pid = up.pid
group by up.pid, up.productname
order by up.pid;

       PID PRODUCTNAME  USERNAMES                     
---------- ------------ ------------------------------
         1 ipad         tom,john,joann                
         3 tv           steve                         
         4 laptop       ann,dexter                    
         6 tablet       ryann,sam
```

or change that to a left outer join to include products with no users, which gets the six rows you said you wanted for the distinct product names:

```
select up.pid, up.productname,
  listagg(ut.username, ',') within group (order by ut.id) as usernames
from userProduct up
left join userTable ut on ut.pid = up.pid
group by up.pid, up.productname
order by up.pid;

       PID PRODUCTNAME  USERNAMES                     
---------- ------------ ------------------------------
         1 ipad         tom,john,joann                
         2 mobile                                     
         3 tv           steve                         
         4 laptop       ann,dexter                    
         5 desktop                                    
         6 tablet       ryann,sam
```

or (moving away from what I think you described, but still showing all products) remove the aggregate to see the original eight rows plus entries for the products with no users:

```
select up.pid, up.productname, ut.id, ut.username
from userProduct up
left join userTable ut on ut.pid = up.pid
order by up.pid, ut.id;

       PID PRODUCTNAME          ID USERNAME
---------- ------------ ---------- --------
         1 ipad                  1 tom     
         1 ipad                  2 john    
         1 ipad                  3 joann   
         2 mobile                          
         3 tv                    4 steve   
         4 laptop                5 ann     
         4 laptop                6 dexter  
         5 desktop                         
         6 tablet                7 ryann   
         6 tablet                8 sam
```

Answer (score 0):

From what is looks like, you just need to add another item to select -

```
select up.pid as pid,ut.username as name, **up.productname** 
from usertable ut,userproduct up where ut.pid = up.pid;
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant because the output will match the rows on basis of inner joins and from the question its quite clear that you want to fetch 6 rows from inner join on pid.On all terms it matches 8 rows with the pid and there is no unmatching column in it.